# PHP variable ('@@') does in my function

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, variables

I am trying to understand this function. What is the purpose of `"@@id@@"` is in this print function.  It's in a php program running jqueryjs, modernizrjs and yenopejs javascript frameworks.

```
function print_delete_warning($id){

    $box=$this->load($this->delete_warning);
    $box=$this->replace("@@id@@",$id, $box);
    return $box;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not a PHP variable. It is simply a piece of text that gets replaced by `$id` in this code; it could just as well be `ID_GOES_HERE` or `!!!`.

For a parallel example... say you want to know how to say "Where is the post office" in Japanese. You open a travel guide, and it says "Where is the [place]" = 「[place]はどこですか。」. Seeing `@@id@@` in the above code and asking about the PHP variable `@@` is effectively like asking "what does `[` mean in Japanese".

Answer (score 1):

it is just a string that will replace in the template.

some people create there own template so they use @@id@@ because it is unique and easy to replace.

for example this is the template:

welcome @@name@@!!

and they use it always like this

```
$name="pinoy";
$box=$this->replace("@@name@@",$name, $box);
```

the output will be:
welcome pinoy!!

in next use will be

```
$name="american";
$box=$this->replace("@@name@@",$name, $box);
```

the output will be:
welcome american!!

Answer (score 0):

You havent given us much to go on. Like the name of the program would have been fine. But from common knowledge, it looks very much like a replace function. What a replace function does is that it

> Replace all occurrences of the search string with the replacement string

i.e, it looks for `"@@id@@"` in `$box` and replaces it with `$id`.

refer to the php documentation for str_replace [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)